# How to get my package to recognize my submodule in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package

I am making a package in python for fun. Here is the structure of my package:

```
shellfun:
    __init__.py
    fibo.py
```

In `fibo.py` I define some functions to return / print fibonacci sequences. `__init__.py` has some fun odds and ends. When I import shellfun, I cannot use the functions I defined in `fibo.py`. How can I get it so it will recognize the functions in `fibo.py`? It recognizes all functions in `__init__.py` just fine.

Thanks, Pb2007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the functions you want to use inside `__init__.py`:

```
from .fibo import *
# or
from .fibo import function_1, function_2 ...
```

Alternatively, when you use `shellfun`, import functions from `fibo` as a submodule:

```
from shellfun.fibo import ...
```

Comment: It says it can't find `fibo.py`. What to do?

Comment: are you using the first solution? what is the error message?

Comment: It's `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fibo'`. Here's a picture: http://prntscr.com/i9abv1

Comment: and `fibo.py` is definitely in the same directory as `__init__.py`?

Comment: yes, `fibo.py` is in the same directory as `__init__.py`. here's proof: http://prntscr.com/i9ag3q

Comment: my apologies, it seems that should be `.fibo`. see updated answer

Comment: you need to use `from .fibo import ...`, not `import .fibo`